# How do you add a picture to Codepen using Dropbox and Javascript then the name of the picture spoken when displayed on the screen? Examples included

Tags: javascript, html, image, dropbox, codepen

I have a question and need help please. I have a Codepen page that I want to create (partially created already, see below link sample) have created which picks 4 random shapes and shows it on screen, one at a time, the shapes are Square, Triangle, Circle or Cross, and when you click the picture again, it moves to the next picture and the computer speaks the name of the previous picture.

What I am trying to do is get the pictures from my Dropbox account and a folder I have shared to select and then display on the screen. The computer speak the word of the picture, i.e picture of Triangle and computer says Triangle. If Dropbox is not suitable please help me with what is good alternative and Free.

I don't know if I've shared my folder in Dropbox correctly, I can't see where the exact URL is found for each picture? or how to link the picture to the associated word.

Below is a sample I got help with to do this with random colours and now would like to have pictures to do a similar thing.

**Sample page I need help with;**
**https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/abNNxRP**

Sample page created where the item works for random colours;
https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/gOrrQzq

Thanks in advance
Nick aka 3DAttic.

```
   'HTML'
  <font size=4> <body onkeydown="speakPrevious()" onkeyup="getNewRandomPicture()">

 <p> <b>This webpage is going to show 4 random pictures of shapes, Square, Cross, Triangle and Circle.
     The algorithm will select at random and <U>You MAY see the same shape several times in a row.          This is expected behavior and NOT a fault.</U>
This will work, using a computer and keyboard or on mobile device using the browser. On the mobile device touch on the text. It may help by placing your finger near the top of the webpage in the phone </p>
<p>On a computer click inside the color and press any keyboard key to move to the next shape.</b></p> 
<p> <font size=4><b><U>If the speach stops, just refresh the page again</b> </p>


   'JS'
     const page = document.querySelector("body");
      page.addEventListener("click", function () {
    speakPrevious();
    getNewRandomPicture();
});

    speakPrevious();
    function speakPrevious() {
    var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
    var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(window.value);
    synth.speak(utterThis);
}

   getNewRandomPicture();
   function getNewRandomPicture() {
   var myArray = ['Triangle','Square', 'Circle', 'Cross' ];
   var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]; document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = rand;
   var oldRand = rand;
   window.value = oldRand;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox removed Public Folder in 2017, you now have the option to share the file and copy the link which you add into your script.

I still need to know how to add this to my original question

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the Dropbox api where you can acces that data by a http request.

There are a few ways to get the images content. Some of that endpoints are:

- filesGetThumbnailBatch

Get the thumbnails of some images. I think is the best option as you can choose the resolution of the images and make it faster.

- filesGetTemporaryLink

Get a 4 houres link of a file

- filesDownload

Download file data

Here is the documentation of the API and all endpoints:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation

Comment: say I can add the images , how do i get the second part to work? you only answered one part. I want tis to work via Java \sript and not HTML, can you help on that?

Comment: To show an image you need to add an image tag to your htm and you cand do this manipulating the HTML dom using javascript for sure.

Comment: <img src={'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+t.thumbnail} width="256px"/>

Comment: Bruno, im not a programmer and need to see the final syntax. can you please show me?

Comment: see the examples ive added to my post

Comment: If you are not a developer the solution I gave is not for you.

Comment: I have got the pictures added to the webpage  but they all appear under each other and got it to speak the names Square, Cross etc at random but they do not match up with the shapes. I just need to have the pictures linked with the words.Any thoughts? see https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/abNNxRP on my progress.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Share the image with Dropbox creating a link
- Go to the link
- Right-click into the image
- Select "Open image in a new tab"
- Copy the URL of the new tab
- Use the URL in src value of a img tag  of your HTML: <img src"your link"></> (see the example)

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/16/16/43/book-5178205_960_720.jpg"></>
```

Comment: how do i get the image to be the correct one with the spoken word, i.e picture of Triangle and when i click mouse the computer says Triangle and moves to the next image which is a Circle and when mouse clicks the commputer says Circle.See my example above showing how i would like it to work.  https://codepen.io/3DAttic/pen/gOrrQzq (this sample is for a different project and shows how it works for random colors)

Answer (score -1):

You can use your Dropbox as a file hosting. Here’s how to use it to host images for your app.

1- Go to your Dropbox Public folder.

2- Upload your images into this folder.

3- Click on an image and select Copy public link.

4- Copy the URL and use it in an image src value.

Hope it going to help you,
Cheers!